# Return an item in a nested list (python)

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm doing a lab for a basic programming class in Python, and I can't figure out how to return a number in a list, in another list.
I'm supposed to return 4 with "one expression and no parenthesis"

```
[1,[2,[3,4]]]
```

Any ideas?
All I've gotten so far is returning [2,[3,4]] and I haven't been able to figure out anything past that.

Comment: Don't forget to check the best answer to your question

Comment: The only way to "return 4" with "one expression and *no parentheses*" that I can think of is this statement: `return 4`

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = [1,[2,[3,4]]]
>>> a[1]
[2, [3, 4]]
>>> a[1][1]
[3, 4]
>>> a[1][1][1]
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

One expression:

```
>>> [1,[2,[3,4]]][1][1][1]
4
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't know, to access the last element of a list you can use negative index. a[-1] means the first element from the end. It's very useful when you want to print elements with position relative to the end.

```
>>> a = [1,[2,[3,4]]]
>>> a[-1]
[2, [3, 4]]
>>> a[-1][-1]
[3, 4]
>>> a[-1][-1][-1]
4
```

Let's say you had a different a. 
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,[1, 1, 1, 1, 2,[1, 1, 1, 3,4]]]
The code above will still give you the last element.

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,[1, 1, 1, 1, 2,[1, 1, 1, 3,4]]]
>>> a[-1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, [1, 1, 1, 3, 4]]
>>> a[-1][-1]
[1, 1, 1, 3, 4]
>>> a[-1][-1][-1]
4
```